# Solve my probability doubt?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

A parent gives birth to two children. One of the child is surely a male, what is the probability of having both male child?

Common answer 1/2
Actual answer 1/3

Comment: And **YOUR** reasoning would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two children, so the distribution of gender can be $(M,M),(M,F),(F,M),(F,F)$. The case $(F,F)$ is excluded. This leaves you with the situation

$(M,M),(M,F),(F,M)$

So the probability of two males is $1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 children. Which child is surely a male? Think about it for a while till you get it.

Comment: You have to consider the order also .

Comment: @SabbirVadharia It was meant for OP to understand that there are 3 cases.